# issue with NSOperationQueue, weakSelf and blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
 [[AHPinterestAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:requestURLPath parameters:nil 
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {


                 [weakSelf.backgroundQueue_ addOperationWithBlock:^{
                     [self doSomeHeavyComputation];                    


                     [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                           [weakSelf.collectionView_ setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
                     [weakSelf.collectionView_ reloadData];
                     [weakSelf.progressHUD_ hide:YES];
                     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] performSelector:@selector(postNotificationName:object:) withObject:@"UIScrollViewDidStopScrolling" afterDelay:0.3];
                     [weakSelf.progressHUD_ hide:YES];


                      }];

                  }];

             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                [weakSelf.progressHUD_ hide:YES];
                [weakSelf.collectionView_.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
                 NSLog(@"Error fetching user data!");
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
             }];
```

For some reason this worked just fine in iOS 5, but not iOS 6 (it crashes). Now I am not going to ask about iOS 6 because it's still under NDA. What I want to know is, whether the code above is wrong? If yes how do I fix it.

If I put the code inside the block outside of the mainQueue then it's fine.
What I am trying to do here is to do the NSOperationQueue mainQueue only after the [self doSomeHeavyComputation] is done. So this is a dependency, how should I add this dependency?

Update:

Here's the crash log if it helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to “unwind” weak references in the block, so please try this:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[client getPath:path parameters:nil success:^(id op, id response) {
    id strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf == nil) return;

    __weak id internalWeakSelf = strongSelf;
    [strongSelf.backgroundQueue_ addOperationWithBlock:^{
        id internalStrongSelf = internalWeakSelf;
        if (internalStrongSelf == nil) return;

        [internalStrongSelf doSomeHeavyComputation];                    

        __weak id internalInternalWeakSelf = internalStrongSelf;
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            id internalInternalStrongSelf = internalInternalWeakSelf;
            if (internalInternalStrongSelf == nil) return;

            [internalInternalStrongSelf reloadCollectionView];
        }];
    }];
}
failure:^(id op, NSError *error) {
    id strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf == nil) return;

    [strongSelf stopProgress];
    NSLog(@"Error fetching user data: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Who recommends you do this and what reasons do they give?

Comment: Cocoa developers recommend this, but I have no URL to provide here. In a multi-threaded environment, a week reference may potentially become `nil` in the middle of the block. However, when you dereference it into the strong one, then the object is guaranteed to exist until the end of the block.

Comment: Yeah, but which cocoa developers? At least a few of the strong self, weak self gymnastics you're doing are unnecessary, since calling methods on nil does nothing.

Comment: @kubi I used this trick at maximum just to demonstrate that `weakSelf` usage in the original question might have unexpected consequences. It does not mean that you must use weak-strong transformations all the time. And my answer containing “please try this” was kind of a debugging technique.

Comment: @kubi **Re: “which cocoa developers?”** WWDC'11 Session 322 ‘Objective-C Advancements in Depth’ at 25:03 aka ‘reference cycle via captured `self`’. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! That is a case that I hadn't considered. Note that the specific issue the WWDC talk mentions is the implicit retaining of self when accessing ivars. In the OP's case, he's not accessing any ivars directly.

Comment: `[self doSomeHeavyComputation];` is suspicious, but I suppose this is a misspelling. So the problem must be with a private `backgroundQueue_`.